# How do I instantiate a module which has a reg port in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, instantiation

I have a module of this type :

```
module rgst(
   input d,...
   output reg [3:0]);

...

endmodule
```

And I want to write a testbench for it:

```
module rgst_tb(
   output reg d,
   ...
   output reg [3:0]q);
   rgst uut(.d(d),...,q(q));
   ...
```

The problem is that I can not instantiate my module in the testbench in this way because `q` is `reg` type.

Comment: why cannot you? Please provide a reproducible example and error messages if any.

Comment: This works in SystemVerilog.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, a module containing testbench code can have either of two styles: the module under test (DUT) is instantiated in the testbench module (TB) itself, or the DUT and TB are separately instantiated in a top-level module that connects them together. You only ever do one, not both; many people new to the language tend to mix them up.

```
+-----------------+         +--------------------------------+
|  module tb      |         | module top                     |
|  +-------------+|         |  +------------+  +------------+|
|  | module dut  ||    or   |  | module tb  |==| module dut ||
|  +-------------+|         |  +------------+  +------------+|
+-----------------+         +--------------------------------+
```

In the first style, the TB module does not need any inputs or outputs, it just needs the wires/regs of the DUT ports declared locally, and manipulated/monitored locally:

```
module tb;
   // Declare ports of DUT as locals inside TB
   wire outval;
   reg inval;

   // Instantiate DUT inside TB module
   dut u1(.in(inval), .out(outval));

   // Stimulus and monitor here
   initial begin
     $monitor(outval);
     inval <= ...;
   end
endmodule
```

In the second style, the TB module is separate and does not instantiate the DUT, thus needs input and output ports to be connected to the DUT in a third, higher level module:

```
module tb(input outval, output reg inval); // TB has ports mirroring DUT ports
  // Stimulus and monitor here
  initial begin
    $monitor(outval);
    inval <= ...;
  end
endmodule

module top;
  // Declare connecting lines here
  wire outval;
  wire inval;

  // Instantiate both TB and DUT here, connecting them together
  tb t1(.outval(outval), .inval(inval));
  dut u1(.in(inval), .out(outval));
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

The misunderstanding I have seen before is that people think you have to connect a reg to a reg.
 **NO**.
It is not like a type where you have to have matching types!

An output port from a module always connects to a `wire`. (or to `logic` if you have System Verilog).

As a rule of thumb:

#### A 'reg' is required whenever you assign to a variable using an `always`<sup>*</sup>  statement.

Unfortunately and very confusing: it has nothing to do with if after synthesis there  is a register! Therefore in System Verilog the type is 'logic' was introduced which removes the 'reg' confusion.

```
wire  this_is_a_wire;
reg   this_is_a_reg;
   assign this_is_a_wire = ....
   always (...)
     this_is_a_reg ...
```

<sup>*</sup><sub>This can also be an always_comb</sub>